# UIImageView as tableview header has initially wrong size?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, xcode7

I'm having trouble displaying an `UIImageView` as `UITableView` header.

When it's initially loaded it's not centered which it should be and its size is 600px? Then when I scroll it jumps to the correct position and adjusts itself to the correct size.

Can anyone tell me what is causing this and possibly how to fix it?

**The problem:**

[image: When the image is initially loaded]

**How it should display initially:**

[image: How it should display initially]

**NOTE:**
When I print out the image height it's 600px wide but should initially be the same as the screenwidth. The `UIImageView` is set to `Aspect Fill`.

**My setup:**

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableImage:UIImageView!

var headerView: UIView!
var headerMaskLayer: CAShapeLayer!
private let kTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 260.0
private let kTableHeaderCutAway: CGFloat = 25.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    tableView.addSubview(headerView)

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: kTableHeaderHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight)

    headerMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    headerMaskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    headerView.layer.mask = headerMaskLayer

    updateHeaderView()

    displayPoster(listBackdrop!)

    //.... rest of code
}

func displayPoster (urlString: String)
{
    if (urlString != ""){

        let newUrl = urlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("w500", withString: "w780")

        self.tableImage.alpha = 0

        let url =  NSURL(string: newUrl)
        // loading image with haneke lib
        self.tableImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1){
            self.tableImage.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) { updateHeaderView() }

func updateHeaderView(){

    var headerRect = CGRect(x: (tableView.bounds.width-tableImage.bounds.width)/2, y: -kTableHeaderHeight, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight)

    if tableView.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeight{
        headerRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
        headerRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y
    }

    headerView.frame = headerRect

    // the image cutaway
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width/2, y: headerRect.height-kTableHeaderCutAway))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height))
    headerMaskLayer?.path = path.CGPath

}
```

**The UIImageView constraints are setup as followed:**
[image: Constraints of table header image]

Comment: Y aren't you using tableviewWillDisplayHeader delegate method for designing your header of tableview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `updateHeaderView()` in your `viewDidLoad()`, which is before the view has had a chance to complete the layout. Try adding that to `viewWillAppear()` method.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you I spent alot of time trying to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while implementing stretchy headers. However calling updateHeaderView() in viewWillAppear() did not work for me.

It should be called from **`viewDidAppear()`** instead.